# how can I correctly get the tableCell value to next tableCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm new here and new to swift .now I'm creating an **invoice app** so I need to display the **invoiceViewController** in next **ViewController** but the cells for the bills in invoice are not coming correctly to next page like being an rangeProblem. I have tried severMethod but I'm getting disappointed . could any one hear help me!..

**this is my InvoiceViewController**

```
enum selecteddScope:Int {
   case Name = 0
   case Code = 1
   case Price = 2
   case Quantity = 3
   case Total = 4
}

import UIKit
import CoreData

class InvoiceViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBOutlet var invoiceNo: UITextField?

@IBOutlet var customerName: UITextField?

@IBOutlet var invoiceDate: UIDatePicker?

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var totalAmountLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var discountLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var netAmountLabel: UILabel!

var selectedCellValues: [String] = []

var invoices: [NSManagedObject] = []
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

var currentInvoice: Invoice?

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

var filteringInvoices: [NSManagedObject] = []

var isSearching = false

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var totalSum = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    loadDataFromDatabases()
    tableView.reloadData()
    
    searchBar.delegate = self
    
    saveToOurCoreData()
    
    searchBarSetuP()
    fetchInvoices()
    tableView.reloadData()
    
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "celll")
    
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

func searchBarSetuP() {
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:(UIScreen.main.bounds.width),height:70))
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Name","Code","Price","Quantity","Total"]
    searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
}

func fetchInvoices() {
    do {
        invoices = try context.fetch(Invoice.fetchRequest())
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching invoice: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func filteringInvoices(with searchText: String) {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productName CONTAINS[c] %@ OR productCode CONTAINS[c] %@ OR unitPrice == %@ OR quantity == %@ OR totalAmount == %@", searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText)
    filteringInvoices = invoices.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        isSearching = true
        filteringInvoices = invoices
    } else {
        isSearching = false
        filteringInvoices(with: searchText)
        // filterContentForSearchText(searchText, scope: searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadDataFromDatabases()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadDataFromDatabases() {
    //Set up Core Data Context
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    //Set up Request
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Invoice")
    
    //Execute request
    do {
        invoices = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch _ as NSError {
        // print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isSearching ? filteringInvoices.count : invoices.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celll", for: indexPath)
    let invoice: Invoice
    if isSearching {
        invoice = filteringInvoices[indexPath.row] as! Invoice
    } else {
        invoice = invoices[indexPath.row] as! Invoice
    }
    // Create labels for each column
    let productNameLabel = UILabel()
    let productCodeLabel = UILabel()
    let unitPriceLabel = UILabel()
    let quantityLabel = UILabel()
    let totalLabel = UILabel()
    
    // Configure label properties
    productNameLabel.text = invoice.productName
    productNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
    productNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    productCodeLabel.text = invoice.productCode
    productCodeLabel.textAlignment = .left
    productCodeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    unitPriceLabel.text = String(invoice.unitPrice)
    unitPriceLabel.textAlignment = .left
    unitPriceLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 180, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    quantityLabel.text = String(invoice.quantity)
    quantityLabel.textAlignment = .left
    quantityLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    totalLabel.text = String(invoice.totalAmount)
    totalLabel.textAlignment = .right
    totalLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 270, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    // Remove existing labels from cell's contentView
    cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() 
}
    
    // Add labels to the cell's contentView
    cell.contentView.addSubview(productNameLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(productCodeLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(unitPriceLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(quantityLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(totalLabel)
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Get the selected item
    
    if let selecteddInvoice = invoices[indexPath.row] as? Invoice {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductDetailViewController") as? ProductDetailViewController {
            controller.selecteddItem = selecteddInvoice
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("Failed to instantiate DetailViewController")
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func onClickSaveInvoice(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //saveToOurCoreData()

    guard UIApplication.shared.delegate is AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    
    // Save the calculated values
    let totalSum = calculateTotalAmount()
    let netAmount = totalSum - 100
 
    do {
        // Pass the calculated values to InvoiceDetailViewController
        if let selectedInvoice = invoices.first as? Invoice {
            
            let section = 0
            let rowIndexes = 0...5
            var selectedCellValues: [String] = []

            for row in rowIndexes {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celll", for: indexPath)
            }

            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                if let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) {
                    for subview in selectedCell.contentView.subviews {
                        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let labelText = label.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(labelText)
                                print("label.text")
                            }
                        }
                        else if let otherLabel1 = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let otherLabel1Text = otherLabel1.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(otherLabel1Text)
                                print("otherLabel1.text")
                            }
                        }
                        else if let otherLabel2 = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let otherLabel2Text = otherLabel2.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(otherLabel2Text)
                            }
                        }
                        else if let otherLabel3 = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let otherLabel3Text = otherLabel3.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(otherLabel3Text)
                            }
                            print(selectedCellValues)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InvoiceDetailViewController") as? InvoiceDetailViewController {
                controller.selectedddItem = selectedInvoice
                controller.cellValues = selectedCellValues
                controller.invoice = selectedInvoice
                controller.invoice?.customer = customerName?.text
                controller.invoice?.number = invoiceNo?.text
                controller.invoice?.amountTotal = String(totalSum)
                controller.invoice?.netTotal = String(netAmount)
                controller.invoice?.date = invoiceDate?.date
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            } else {
                print("Failed to instantiate InvoiceDetailViewController")
            }
        }
    } catch _ as NSError {
       // print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func saveToOurCoreData() {
    guard UIApplication.shared.delegate is AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Invoice")
    
    do {
        invoices = try context.fetch(request)
        
        // Calculate total amount
        var totalSum = 0.0
        for invoice in invoices {
            if let amount = invoice.value(forKey: "totalAmount") as? Double {
                totalSum += amount
            }
        }
        totalAmountLabel.text = String(totalSum)
        
        // Calculate net amount
        let netAmount = totalSum - 100
        netAmountLabel.text = String(netAmount)
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}

func calculateTotalAmount() -> Double {
    var totalSum = 0.0
    
    for invoice in invoices {
        if let amount = invoice.value(forKey: "totalAmount") as? Double {
            totalSum += amount
        }
    }
    
    return totalSum
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        
        // Delete the row from the data source
        let invoice = invoices[indexPath.row] as? Invoice
        let name = invoice!.productName
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Selected row: \(indexPath.row) (\(name))", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this Product?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        
        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive) { [self] _ in
            
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            context.delete(invoice!)
            
            do {
                try context.save()
                loadDataFromDatabases()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            }
            catch {
                fatalError("Error saving context: \(error)")
            }
        }
        //  loadDataFromDatabase()
        alertController.addAction(deleteAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "invoiceDetailViewController" {
        let destinationVC1 = segue.destination as! InvoiceDetailViewController
    }
  }
}


extension InvoiceViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text ?? "", scope: selectedScope)
}
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: Int) {
    var predicate: NSPredicate?
    
    switch scope {
    case 0: // Name
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
    case 1: // Code
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "productCode CONTAINS[c] %@", searchText)
    case 2: // Price
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "unitPrice == %@", searchText)
    case 3: // Quantity
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "quantity == %@", searchText)
    case 4: // Amount
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "totalAmount == %@", searchText)
    default:
        predicate = nil
    }
    
    if let predicate = predicate {
        filteringInvoices = invoices.filter { predicate.evaluate(with: $0) }
    } else {
        filteringInvoices = invoices
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

and **this is my detailInvoiceViewController**

```
class InvoiceDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var labelOfDate: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var labelOfCustomer: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var labelOfNumber: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var labelOfTotalAmount: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var labelOfNetAmount: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var tableViewww: UITableView!

var cellValues: [String] = []

var selectedddItem: Invoice?
var invoice: Invoice?
var invoices: [Invoice] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
 //   tableViewww.reloadData()
    
    if let invoice = selectedddItem {
        labelOfCustomer.text = invoice.customer
        labelOfNumber.text = invoice.number
        labelOfTotalAmount.text = invoice.amountTotal
        labelOfNetAmount.text = invoice.netTotal
        
        // Convert Date to String using a DateFormatter
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        if let date = invoice.date {
            labelOfDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            labelOfDate.text = ""
        }
        // Update cell values
                   cellValues = [
                       invoice.productName ?? "",
                       invoice.productCode ?? "",
                       String(invoice.unitPrice),
                       String(invoice.quantity),
                       String(invoice.totalAmount),
                   ]
                   tableViewww.reloadData()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows based on your data
    return cellValues.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cells", for: indexPath)
  
    let productNameLabel1 = UILabel()
    let productCodeLabel2 = UILabel()
    let unitPriceLabel3 = UILabel()
    let quantityLabel4 = UILabel()
    let totalLabel5 = UILabel()

    productNameLabel1.text = cellValues[indexPath.row]
    productNameLabel1.textAlignment = .left
    productNameLabel1.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)

  productCodeLabel2.text = cellValues[1]
    productCodeLabel2.textAlignment = .left
    productCodeLabel2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)

  unitPriceLabel3.text = cellValues[2]
    unitPriceLabel3.textAlignment = .left
    unitPriceLabel3.frame = CGRect(x: 180, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)

   quantityLabel4.text = cellValues[3]
    quantityLabel4.textAlignment = .left
    quantityLabel4.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)

  totalLabel5.text = cellValues[4]
    totalLabel5.textAlignment = .right
    totalLabel5.frame = CGRect(x: 270, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)

    cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

    cell.contentView.addSubview(productNameLabel1)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(productCodeLabel2)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(unitPriceLabel3)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(quantityLabel4)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(totalLabel5)
    //tableViewww.reloadData()
    return cell
 }
}
```

I have tried for this cells displaying in next ViewController cell but it showing in incorrect manner of being incorrect range.

I will share my simulator screenshots so you guys can point out what I'm saying and my problem.

Comment: there is many ambiguous things in your detail controller

Comment: also the images are not available

Comment: there are two image links that  I have separated with the qstn. @ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZGH1.png first image and https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQOML.png second image @ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: provide image link from some other open web platform  form so that I can see

Comment: I don't know that why you are not getting that image. if you click on that link you can see my screenshots. or else you can copy and paste in your chrome or safari you can see it. @ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: safari unable to open the image you can post here the link of image. upload image to online on some platform where u can share the url

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadII is that now can you see those pictures ?

Comment: https://imgbb.com upload here and share the link

Comment: hey... I have updated the qstn with images just try to see the full qstn.@ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: https://ibb.co/ctZtyLz this is how ur images are shown

Comment: I don't know for you that why happens like this. because I checked in my friends Mac but there is no problem to see that pic . https://ibb.co/qRfdKtW and
https://ibb.co/gS1Dg2w just see this

Comment: the issues is there is 2 rows on invoice and 5 on detail controller with shuffle values?

Comment: no . in invoice I can create more rows by clicking on "ADD ITEM" . I really needs that rows to be displayed on my detail controller cells. by looking u can understand its clearly of an bill report exactly I want to display like that.

Comment: if you want to add item then you just have to append the array and reload tableview after appending the array

Comment: I think you didn't understand my stn.@ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: my qstn is to pass those cells into the cells I have created in invoice detail. you can see two pics right?. I need to pass that first pic cells into the second pic cells. range should be correct. it means that how much cells are their in invoice after clicking save all should passs into the detail invoice .@ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: so there is two cell apple and orange and you pass same to detail voice after save button? right

Comment: your code is messy. you just have to pass invoices (array) to detail controller. not pass the single object Invoice.

Comment: yes that's only I needed @ZeeshanAhmadII

Comment: controller.invoices = invoices as? [Invoice] ?? []

Comment: can I ask you oneThing after this save displayed all thing I have created an another TableViewController of being to be see an listView of Invoice but the problem is when ever I being clicking the save button in InvoiceViewController the values of tableView there remains same after saving it is not clearing by this reason the listView is keep on saving in one cell. can you help me to sort it?        @ZeeshanAhmadII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This the detail controller.

```
class InvoiceDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet var labelOfDate: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var labelOfCustomer: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var labelOfNumber: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var labelOfTotalAmount: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var labelOfNetAmount: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet var tableViewww: UITableView!
    
    var cellValues: [String] = []
    
    var selectedddItem: Invoice?
    var invoice: Invoice?
    var invoices: [Invoice] = [] {
        didSet {tableView.reloadData()}
     }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
     //   tableViewww.reloadData()
        
        if let invoice = selectedddItem {
            labelOfCustomer.text = invoice.customer
            labelOfNumber.text = invoice.number
            labelOfTotalAmount.text = invoice.amountTotal
            labelOfNetAmount.text = invoice.netTotal
            
            // Convert Date to String using a DateFormatter
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
            if let date = invoice.date {
                labelOfDate.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            } else {
                labelOfDate.text = ""
            }
            // Update cell values
                      
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return invoices.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celll", for: indexPath)
    let invoice: Invoice
    if isSearching {
        invoice = filteringInvoices[indexPath.row] as! Invoice
    } else {
        invoice = invoices[indexPath.row] as! Invoice
    }
    // Create labels for each column
    let productNameLabel = UILabel()
    let productCodeLabel = UILabel()
    let unitPriceLabel = UILabel()
    let quantityLabel = UILabel()
    let totalLabel = UILabel()
    
    // Configure label properties
    productNameLabel.text = invoice.productName
    productNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
    productNameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    productCodeLabel.text = invoice.productCode
    productCodeLabel.textAlignment = .left
    productCodeLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    unitPriceLabel.text = String(invoice.unitPrice)
    unitPriceLabel.textAlignment = .left
    unitPriceLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 180, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    quantityLabel.text = String(invoice.quantity)
    quantityLabel.textAlignment = .left
    quantityLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    totalLabel.text = String(invoice.totalAmount)
    totalLabel.textAlignment = .right
    totalLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 270, y: 10, width: 100, height: 30)
    
    // Remove existing labels from cell's contentView
    cell.contentView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() 
 }
    
    // Add labels to the cell's contentView
    cell.contentView.addSubview(productNameLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(productCodeLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(unitPriceLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(quantityLabel)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(totalLabel)
    
    return cell
   }
 }
```

the button action

```
  @IBAction func onClickSaveInvoice(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //saveToOurCoreData()

    guard UIApplication.shared.delegate is AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    
    // Save the calculated values
    let totalSum = calculateTotalAmount()
    let netAmount = totalSum - 100
 
    do {
        // Pass the calculated values to InvoiceDetailViewController
        if let selectedInvoice = invoices.first as? Invoice {
            
            let section = 0
            let rowIndexes = 0...5
            var selectedCellValues: [String] = []

            for row in rowIndexes {
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celll", for: indexPath)
            }

            if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                if let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedIndexPath) {
                    for subview in selectedCell.contentView.subviews {
                        if let label = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let labelText = label.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(labelText)
                                print("label.text")
                            }
                        }
                        else if let otherLabel1 = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let otherLabel1Text = otherLabel1.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(otherLabel1Text)
                                print("otherLabel1.text")
                            }
                        }
                        else if let otherLabel2 = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let otherLabel2Text = otherLabel2.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(otherLabel2Text)
                            }
                        }
                        else if let otherLabel3 = subview as? UILabel {
                            if let otherLabel3Text = otherLabel3.text {
                                selectedCellValues.append(otherLabel3Text)
                            }
                            print(selectedCellValues)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InvoiceDetailViewController") as? InvoiceDetailViewController {
                controller.selectedddItem = selectedInvoice
                controller.invoices = invoices as? [Invoice] ?? []
                controller.invoice = selectedInvoice
                controller.invoice?.customer = customerName?.text
                controller.invoice?.number = invoiceNo?.text
                controller.invoice?.amountTotal = String(totalSum)
                controller.invoice?.netTotal = String(netAmount)
                controller.invoice?.date = invoiceDate?.date
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
            } else {
                print("Failed to instantiate InvoiceDetailViewController")
            }
        }
    } catch _ as NSError {
       // print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: didSet {tableView.reloadData()}
it showing an error of" Reference to member 'reloadData' cannot be resolved without a contextual type" so I changed this tableView into my outlet name as tableViewww the error was gone but when I build the app it shows as "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: any way thank you very much @zeeshan its worked I have commanded those lines .

Comment: replace  tableView.reloadData() with tableViewww.reloadData().

Comment: its the naming issue you named tableView as tableViewww

Comment: I don't think so because I have tried with those two names two of them were error .thats why I commanded and build it this Time no error and I have got the output .

Comment: just build the project the error line automatically vanished

Comment: yeah I have removed that line from code

Comment: can I ask you oneThing after this save displayed all thing I have created an another TableViewController of being to be see an listView of Invoice but the problem is when ever I being clicking the save button in InvoiceViewController the values of tableView there remains same after saving it is not clearing by this reason the listView is keep on saving in one cell. can you help me to sort it?

Comment: actually I didn't get your properly. So its hard to me. Other wise your issues are simple you just have to read out the appending and removing items from array and reload tables. Download example projects from git hub which performs CURD operation over tableview with array